# Xcode, create two the same MyMoviePlayerController in two ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a ViewController:

```
ReadViewController.h
ReadViewController.m
```

And I have a MPMoviePlayerController inside ReadViewController:

```
ReadViewController.h
@interface ReadViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyMoviePlayerController   *myPlayView;
@end



ReadViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   .....
   .....
   .....
   [self.view addSubview:self.myPlayView.view];
}
```

I created two objects of ReadViewController which one is small size used for “preview” and another is Screen Size.
I put the two ViewControllers in two place:

```
ReadViewController *bigSizeReadViewController = [[ReadViewController alloc] init]; 
//put bigSizeReadViewController inside an UITabBarController
```

.....

```
ReadViewController *smallSizeReadViewController = [[ReadViewController alloc] init]; 
smallSizeReadViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(200, 300, 400, 600);
[......  addSubView:smallSizeReadViewController.view];
```

I put the two ViewControllers in two place.
When I run this on IPAD Simulator,  self.myPlayView inside small size's ReadViewController can be played normally.
But self.myPlayView inside big size's ReadViewController can not be played normally and show black screen.

Could anyone help me with this issue?
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize and setup each of the myPlayView properties separately, and start playing them each individually.

There will be no guarantees that they will be synchronized as they are independent AVPLayer objects.  You;ll have to write the extra code to keep them in sync.